# What port does Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio use for database connections?

Tags: sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17 to connect to a remote Microsoft SQL Server database.  Looking at the connection dialog of Studio 17, I don't see any port number setting.  Google tells me that Studio uses port 1433 by default.

I tried to use `telnet` to check if port 1433 is listening on the remote server: `telnet example.company.com 1433`

However, the connection failed.  How can I find the port used for this database connection?

Comment: You could use nmap to detect server active ports and try to connect to the actives. for example,  ***nmap scanme.nmap.org***

Comment: Is it a named instance or is it the default name (`MSSQLSERVER`)?

Answer (score 0):

You could connect SSMS to your DB, run ProcessExplorer and examine the properties of ssms.exe. On the "TCP/IP" tab you possibly find what you are asking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have connectivity to the server first. Since you mentioned "remote" there could be a firewall in the way, so your solution is going to depend on your network topology.
Can you ping the server? If ping works, I would reach out to the owner of the server and verify the DB connection parameters. Maybe your IP needs to be whitelisted. Etc. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the server host has inbound port 1433 enabled, and whether TCP/IP is enabled using the SQL server configuration manager. If the SQL server instance in question sits on the cloud, you might want to check the specific provider's firewall rules on the container and adjust to permit 1433 inbound connections. The port setting entirely lies on where the actual SQL server instance sits. The management studio in your remote client will not be using any port.